# Как динамически менять количество страниц во ViewPager2?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

ViewPager2 имеет метод getItemCount(), в котором задаём количество страниц. К примеру есть приложение, в котором нужно создавать по нажатию новый фрагмент и отображать это всё во ViewPager2. Соответственно, заранее мы не знаем кол-во страниц. Как опираясь на кол-во созданных фрагментов установить кол-во страниц для ViewPager2. Пробовал поставить кол-во страниц через getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount(), но не получилось.

Answer (score 0):

Для этой задачи нужно написать свой adapter, к примеру

```
class ListAdapter() : RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ViewHolder>()
```

Внутри которого будет список который соответствует страницам

```
val list = ArrayList<String>()
```

Нужно переназначить метод так что бы количество возвращало из нашего списка

```
override fun getItemCount() = list.size
```

И добавлять

```
adapter.list.add("New Item")
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```